# "Activate" active characters in argument passed as macro

Tags: macros, characters, catcodes

Let's say I have some macro (`\iPrint` in the MWE) that internally uses active characters to interpret its argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\|
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~#1~{\textbf{#1}}%
  }
\def\iPrint{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \iPrintX
}
\def\iPrintX#1{%
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\def\temp{This |doesn't work|, though :-(}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \iPrint{This |works pretty| well!}
  \item \iPrint{\temp}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: Output]

AFAIU the issue, catcodes are assigned at definition time of a macro: When `\temp` is defined, `|` is not active. However, is there something I can do within `\iPrint` to make it active anyway? Some sort of recoding the argument with the current catcodes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say

```
\def\temp{This |doesn't work|, though :-(}
```

the catcode of `|` is fixed and setting `` \catcode`|=\active `` has no effect when the expansion of `\temp` is performed: the `|` characters in the replacement text have category code 12.

One can use `\scantokens` to reassign category codes, but the macros must be expanded *before* `\scantokens` comes into play:

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\|
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~#1~{\textbf{#1}}%
  }
\def\iPrint#1{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \protected@edef\reserved@iprint{\noexpand\scantokens{#1\noexpand\empty}}\reserved@iprint
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

If the input to `\iPrint` is known to be only text or a macro (say `\iPrint{\temp}`), then the simpler

```
\def\iPrint#1{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \scantokens\expandafter{#1\empty}%
  \endgroup}
```

would work. If the argument is more complicated (text and macros), then the more complicated approach with `\protected@edef` appears to be necessary; it will expand all macros, but won't go too much deeply with "protected" macros.

The `\empty` at the end of the argument to `\scantokens` is customary to avoid a spurious space: `\scantokens` actually emulates the input of a file and all files are implicitly terminated with an empty line. Inside `\protected@edef` it mustn't be expanded, so we add `\noexpand` in front of it.

(Thanks to Bruno Le Floch for correcting an inaccuracy.)

Comment: Your last paragraph is inaccurate. The `\noexpand` at the end of the argument to `\scantokens` can be replaced by `\relax`, or by `\empty`. It's only effect is that the last line of the virtual file built by `\scantokens` ends with a control word, hence a newline doesn't produce a space. As it is, your `\noexpand` acts on `\endgroup`, which luckily does nothing bad.

Answer (score 8):

Catcodes are assigned when a input character is read. TeX then looks up the current value for this input and attaches the catcode. Later it can not be changed. So you must reread the input if you want to change it. E.g. by writing it to a file and then reinput this file. Or by using `\scantokens`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\|
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~#1~{\textbf{#1}}%
  }
\def\iPrint{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\|=\active
  \iPrintX
}
\def\iPrintX#1{%
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\def\temp{This |doesn't work|, though :-(\relax}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \iPrint{This |works pretty| well!}
  \item \iPrint{\scantokens\expandafter{\temp}}.
  \item \iPrint{\temp}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I was looking for a way to do it on the callee side, which is what egreg's solution provides.