# Active quotes in macro

Tags: macros, csquotes

I would like to use [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) to activate quotes. That is, taking

```
This is a "quote" inside other text.
```

and turning it into

```
This is a ``quote'' inside other text.
```

`csquotes` makes this possible via

```
\usepackage{csquotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes
\MakeOuterQuote{"}\EnableQuotes
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes
\begin{document}

This is a "quote" inside other text.

\MakeOuterQuote{"}\EnableQuotes

This is a "quote" inside other text.

\end{document}
```

However, my workflow writes content into a macro:

```
\newcommand{\somemacro}{This is a "quote" inside other text.}
```

This does not allow one to render the quotes automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes
\newcommand{\somequote}{This is a "quote" inside other text.}
\begin{document}

This is a "quote" inside other text.

\MakeOuterQuote{"}\EnableQuotes

\somequote

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices include:

1. Adjusting your workflow to set the content as-is rather than inside a macro, since macro arguments are stored using the catcodes at the time of definition.
2. Make sure to write your macro in such a way that the quotes are active at the time of definition, since [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) issues the activation `\EnableQuotes` only `\AtBeginDocument` to avoid problems inside the preamble (from [`csquotes.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.sty)):

   ```
   \newrobustcmd*{\EnableQuotes}{}
   \newrobustcmd*{\DisableQuotes}{}
   \newrobustcmd*{\VerbatimQuotes}{}
   \newrobustcmd*{\DeleteQuotes}{\csq@mkdelete}

   \AtBeginDocument{%
     \protected\def\EnableQuotes{\csq@mkenable}%
     \protected\def\DisableQuotes{\csq@mkdisable}%
     \protected\def\VerbatimQuotes{\csq@mkverbatim}}
   ```

   For example, insert the definition inside the `document` environment, since then `"` will be active:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{csquotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes
   \MakeOuterQuote{"}\EnableQuotes
   \begin{document}

   This is a "quote" inside other text.

   \newcommand{\somequote}{This is a "quote" inside other text.}% " is active here

   \somequote

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Use the technique described in ["Activate" active characters in argument passed as macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42592/5764) to re-activate the made-active quotes `"`:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{csquotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes
   \MakeOuterQuote{"}\EnableQuotes
   \newcommand{\somequote}{This is a "quote" inside other text.}% " is not active here
   \begin{document}

   This is a "quote" inside other text.

   \begingroup
   \catcode`\"=\active% Re-activate "
   \scantokens\expandafter{\somequote\empty}%
   \endgroup

   \end{document}
   ```