# Active character in a command

Tags: macros, characters, catcodes

I would like `\forall` to trigger a certain behavior (for the purpose of the example below: change the text color to red), which is cancelled when the next `(` is encountered. I can make this work when the `(` in question is not within a command, but not when it is. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\let\oldforall\forall

\renewcommand{\forall}{%
\oldforall%
\color[rgb]{1,0,0}%
\catcode`(=\active%
}

\let\lparen=(

\catcode`(=\active
\renewcommand{(}{%
\color[rgb]{0,0,0}%
\catcode`(=12\relax%
\lparen}%
\catcode`(=12

\newcommand{\acommand}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

This works: $\forall x(x^2\geq0)$

This doesn't: \acommand{$\forall x(x^2\geq0)$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need a solution that doesn't involve changing the definition of `\acommand`, as this has to work for *any* macro that `(` may find itself in.

I can understand from [“Activate” active characters in argument passed as macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42592/activate-active-characters-in-argument-passed-as-macro) that the issue is that the `(` is passed as a passive character to the macro, at which point it is too late to make it active. But I do not understand the solution, so I'm not able to adapt it to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catcodes get frozen when a macro fetches its argument.

You can make a variant using the more flexible notion of "math activation", which escapes that restriction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsmath}
% added to test compatibility, because it is not generally
% possibly to have a globally (math) active ( with amsmath
% but here activation is done only temporarily

\let\oldforall\forall

\renewcommand{\forall}{%
    \oldforall
    \color[rgb]{1,0,0}%
    \edef\mathcodeofleftparen{\the\mathcode`\(}%
    \mathcode`\(="8000
}

\catcode`(=\active
\def({%
    \color[rgb]{0,0,0}%
    \mathcode`\(=\mathcodeofleftparen\relax
    \string(}
\catcode`(=12

\newcommand{\acommand}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

This works: $\forall x(x^2\geq0), \forall y(y^3\leq0)$

This too: \acommand{$\forall x(x^2\geq0), \forall y(y^3\leq0)$}

By the way, spacing does not look ideal.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

One may also envision redefining `\forall` as a delimited macro if it is always systematically used with a `(`.

But either a delimited macro or the approach in the code above does not allow things like  `\forall x \left(...`. Thus I recommend a much simpler approach based on suitable mark-up, for example

```
\newcommand*{\cforall}[1]{\forall\color[rgb]{1,0,0}#1\color[rgb]{0,0,0}}
```

to be used as `\cforall {x}(stuff)`, or `\cforall x\left(stuff\right)` etc...

Comment: Thank you for your help! With two modifications, your solution worked in my non-MWE real document. 1) The solution does not work if there are multiple occurrences of '\forall' before the first '('. I therefore moved \edef\mathcodeofleftparen{\the\mathcode`\(}% outside of the macro. 2) \boldsymbol cannot be used while '(' is active. I found a workaround.

Comment: @Casper The incompatibility of a math active `(`  with `\boldsymbol` (from `amsmath`)  is a known issue related to `\resetMathstrut@` inner macro of `amsmath`. You can check the source code of package `mathastext` to find a way to redefine `\resetMathstrut@` in a way which solves that problem. The code in `mathastext.sty` however needs some adjustment for general use, as it makes use of math groups defined by `mathastext`.